# Object De-structuring works when I am not wrapping it up in a function

Tags: javascript

Thank you for your guidance.

I'd like to find a simple way of passing function arguments, to populate a de-structured variable. 
Hit a stumbling block, is this possible? As I'd like to then use a Rest... operator and tidy up my code - it is an incredible syntax if possible.

This Works:

```
let cat = {
    Models: {
        brand: ['sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3', 'sku4', 'sku5']
    }
};
let {brand} = cat.Models;
for (let [key,value] of Object.entries(brand)) {
    console.log(`${key} ${value}`)
};
```

This does not:

```
function wrapper(b) {
    let {b} = skus.Models;
    for (let [key,value] of Object.entries(b)) {
        console.log(`${key} ${value}`)
    };
}
wrapper('brand');
```

Comment: check the code you posted, it seems it's not , you are recedlaring a variable b and you are referring to an undeclared variable skus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destructure a dynamic key but you need to give it a different name like

```
function wrapper(b) {
    let {[b]: model} = skus.Models;
    for (let [key,value] of Object.entries(model)) {
        console.log(`${key} ${value}`)
    };
}
wrapper('brand');
```

Comment: many, many thanks for your swift response and accurate answer. It is incredibly helpful. I just stumbled across the de-structuring syntax and was not familiar with ```{[b]: model}``` notion. Appreciate your guidance, I learnt something new today. Have a great day.

Comment: This works fine but I would argue there's now no improvement on the "old-fashioned" way of doing this: `let model = skus.Models[b];`

Comment: @RobinZigmond I agree with you